# Error 1064 during import

Tags: mysql, migration

When I try to import my database on the production server, I get:

> SQL запрос:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE `articles` (
>   `id_art` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `id_section` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `id_ct` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `fesid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
>   `date_art` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `title_art` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>   `meta_art` longtext,
>   `short_art` text NOT NULL,
>   `full_art` longtext NOT NULL,
>   `foto_art` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `foto_art_text` text,
>   `coordinates_art` longtext,
>   `hot` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`id_art`),
>   KEY `articles_fesid_c163d690_uniq` (`fesid`),
>   KEY `articles_id_ct_af67450c_uniq` (`id_ct`),
>   KEY `articles_id_section_8f87bacd_uniq` (`id_section`)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4060 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
> ```
>
> Ответ MySQL: Документация
>
> ```
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near '(6) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `title_art` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
>   `meta_art` longtext,
>   ' at line 6
> ```

What causing this and do I fix that?

I tried to import with Phpmyadmin and by `mysql -u user -p basename < filename.sql`

I made export with `mysqldump`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems to be causing the problem

```
`date_art` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
```

This works

```
`date_art` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
```

Is the version of the database you exported from the same as you are importing to?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572209/why-doesnt-mysql-support-millisecond-microsecond-precision

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html